# Recursion with Double Call (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion

Can someone please explain to me how exactly this adds up to 26?

I get confused by the 'double call'. Maybe I just don't understand recursion as well as I think I do.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rec(int * N, int max) {
    if (max < 0)
        return 0;

    return N[max] + rec(N, max - 1) + rec(N, max - 2); 
}

int main() {
   const int max = 5;
    int N[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int f = rec(N, max - 1);

    cout << f << endl; 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take out your pencil and paper, and draw it up. The first call from main will return `5 + something + something_else`. The first `something` will return `4 + something_else + yet_something`. Just continue until you reach `return 0`, and then work your way back up.

Comment: Too good ways: 1. Get a debugger. Fire the program up in the debugger. Step through the code and watch the flow. 2. Do it by hand and walk through all of the calls with pen and paper.

Comment: Closing this as too broad. "good answers would be too long for this format" – indeed. We ain't gonna draw the whole call stack for you. You should be doing that.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Someone might. Me, I'd write a program to do it. Leads to a third option: insert print statements that describe what's happening at every step into the program, execute, and read the results.

Comment: If a double recursion call is confusing you, maybe you need to think more literally and simply. When a function call is reached in running code, that function is called with those arguments. It's that simple. One thing happens at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int f = rec(N, 4)
      = N[4] + rec(N, 3) + rec(N, 2)
      = 5 + (N[3] + rec(N, 2) + rec(N, 1)) + (N[2] + rec(N, 1) + rec(N, 0))
      = 5 + (4 + (N[2] + rec(N, 1) + rec(N, 0)) + (N[1] + rec(N, 0) + rec(N, -1)) + (3 + (N[1] + rec(N, 0) + rec(N, -1)) + (N[0] + rec(N, -1) + rec(N, -2)))
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + rec(N, 1) + rec(N, 0)) + (2 + rec(N, 0) + 0) + (3 + (2 + rec(N, 0) + 0) + (1 + 0 + 0))
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + (N[1] + rec(N, 0) + rec(N, -1)) + (N[0] + rec(N, -1) + rec(N, -2))) + (2 + (N[0] + rec(N, -1) + rec(N, -2)) + 0) + (3 + (2 + (N[0] + rec(N, -1) + rec(N, -2)) + 0) + 1)
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + (N[0] + rec(N, -1) + rec(N, -2)) + 0) + (1 + 0 + 0)) + (2 + (1 + 0 + 0) + 0) + (3 + (2 + (1 + 0 + 0) + 0) + 1))
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + (1 + 0 + 0) + 0) + 1) + (2 + 1 + 0) + (3 + (2 + 1 + 0) + 1))
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + (2 + 1 + 0) + 1) + 3 + (3 + 3 + 1))
      = 5 + (4 + (3 + 3 + 1) + 3 + 7)
      = 5 + (4 + 7 + 10)
      = 5 + 21
      = 26
```

And as suggested above, the following code generates the entire expression that, when evaluated, equals 26. It can also be played with to generate step-by-step work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string rec(string * N, int max) {
    if (max < 0)
        return "0";

    auto a = rec(N, max - 1), b = rec(N, max - 2);

    return "(" + N[max] + " + " + a + " + " + b + ")";
}

int main() {
    const int max = 5;
    string N[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    auto f = rec(N, max - 1);

    cout << f << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand the way it works (not the code, but the first part of your answer). I'm also unfamiliar with auto specifier, so I'll have to look that up as well.